# removing missing observations from model fit within shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny.  I am trying to allow users to select variables from a drop down menu to visualize, and also include a custom model fit.  However, one of my y variables has missing values.  How can I remove these values from the model fit?  This is not a problem for the plot without fitted values, but once I add these it produces an error:

```
d <- data.frame(y1 = rnorm(100),
                y2 = c(NA,rnorm(99)),
                x = rnorm(100))

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    varSelectInput("variable", "Variable:", d[,c("y1","y2")]),
    plotOutput("data")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    fit <- reactive({
        mod <- lm(as.formula(paste(input$variable, " ~ x")), d)
        fit <- data.frame(x =d$x,
                             y = fitted(mod))
        return(fit)
    })


    output$data <- renderPlot({
      fit <- fit()
      ggplot(d, aes(y = !!input$variable, x= x))+
        geom_point() +geom_line()+
        geom_line(data = fit,
                  aes(x, y), color="red",size = 1, linetype = 2)
    })
  }
)
```

The problem is within the reactive function.  I have tried the typical ways to filter out missing values (e.g. `d <- d[!is.na(input$variable),]` but this does not work

Comment: maybe something like this: `d[!is.na(d[[input$variable]]),]` - you need to reference the data frame when specifying the column with `input$variable`

Comment: Why don't you just do `geom_smooth(method="lm", ...)`? No need to fit a model at all.

Comment: @Edward am actually using an exponential fit and was having other difficulties getting the formula to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben's suggestion in comment works: `d[!is.na(d[[input$variable]]),]`